# How to deploy react app with firebase as databse?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

It's my first time deploying a react app with firebase as my database. I always get this error in my github whenever i try to deploy my react app. Can someone help me with my problem.

[image: This is the error i'm getting in my github]

[image: This is my workflow file]

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your code. Can you edit your question and add that part of your code as text?

Comment: You're getting lint errors which are causing the build to fail. You'll need to either fix those lint errors, or use `eslint-disable` comments to tell eslint that they're not actually errors

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)